# Use existing consumer_id and consumer_secret when provisioning WSO2 app

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm migrating from Apigee to WSO2 and would like to know if it's possible to migrate Apigee's "Developer Apps" to WSO2 such that I can re-use the same consumer_key and consumer_secret.

I found [WSO2's Store APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Store+APIs), and I'm able to programatically

1. Create the WSO2 App,
2. Subscribe the WSO2 App to my published APIs.

From Apigee, I can also retrieve the old consumer_key & consumer_secret,
so I just need a way to overwrite the key & secret in WSO2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution.

After creating the App via the Store APIs, I located the respective credentials in the DB tables. Then I updated 3 table rows and I was able to reuse the same credentials for Apigee and WSO2.